# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Потоки

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность

Как может быть ошибка?:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects+<>c__DisplayClass101_1.<getListStringUrlTexture>b__2 () (at Assets/TerrainTools/StampToolExtended/PlacementObjects.cs:1648)
```

Когда я использую список:

```
public List<string> getListStringUrlTexture()
{
    List<string> listStringUrlTexture = new List<string>();
    List<Thread> listThreads = new List<Thread>();
    string path;
    for (int i = 0; i < GamObjArrayTexture.Length; i++)
    {
        if (GamObjArrayTexture[i] != null)
        {
            // string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[i]);
            // listStringUrlTexture.Add(path);
            listThreads.Add(new Thread(() => { path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[i]); listStringUrlTexture.Add(path); }));
        }
    }
    listThreads.ForEach(x => x.Start());
    listThreads.ForEach(x => x.Join());
    return (listStringUrlTexture.Count > 0) ? listStringUrlTexture : null;
}
```

Ошибка в строке : `listThreads.Add(new Thread(() => { path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[i]); listStringUrlTexture.Add(path); }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл не ждет. Счетчик цикла продолжает увеличиваться, пока не станет равен длине списка.

```
if (GamObjArrayTexture[i] != null)
{
    int index = i;
    listThreads.Add(new Thread(() => { 
        string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[index]);
        listStringUrlTexture.Add(path); 
    }));
}
```

Comment: UnityException: GetAssetPath can only be called from the main thread.

Comment: Стала возникать. в строке string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[index]);

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Это уже другой вопрос. На вопрос из вопроса я ответил.

Comment: Возможно в потоке создать поток и вернуть значение из потока (дочернего), а потом продолжить выполнять основной поток?